# Android refusing to disable dark mode

Tags: android, react-native, android-darkmode

I have a project with two apps written in React Native. Since I do not currently support a dark theme, users with dark-mode enabled on their devices get bad colors in my app. Therefore I want to disable the dark-mode in my app, until the time I have support for it.

In my first application, I have successfully disabled dark mode. But in my second app, I did the exact same thing, but still dark mode affects my colors. This is how my styles.xml looks like, and I also do not have any styles-night.xml or anything like that.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myappname">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      
      <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="secretkey"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
          tools:targetApi="q">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have cleaned the build, and rebuilt it again, but still to no effect. Am I missing something? I know there is an option to disable the dark mode in the onCreate function, but that will just recreate the activity and thus slow down the app startup, which I do not want.

Answer (score -2):

It's complicade because you can try many things but if you buy a theme of other developer maybe the code have lines to force the dark mode. I bought a theme a have this lines, like this:

```
export const useTheme = () => {
const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
const forceDark = useSelector(state => state.application.force_dark);
const themeStorage = useSelector(state => state.application.theme);
const listTheme = ThemeSupport.filter(item => item.theme == themeStorage);
const theme = listTheme.length > 0 ? listTheme[0] : DefaultTheme;

if (forceDark) {
  return {theme: theme.dark, colors: theme.dark.colors}; <--- change here
}
if (forceDark === false) {
  return {theme: theme.light, colors: theme.light.colors};
}
return isDarkMode
  ? {theme: theme.dark, colors: theme.dark.colors} <----- change here
  : {theme: theme.light, colors: theme.light.colors};
};
```

So I change dark to ligth and solved my problem.